# How to determine the first triangle (out of a set of triangles) passed through by a 3-D ray?

Tags: python, algorithm, image-processing, geometry

I am trying to solve the following problem in Python. The problem comes from an image processing problem when i use the Finite Element Method.

In my problem, I have a set of triangles  and a ray. Each  triangle consists of three 3-D points,  and the ray is in the form of a 3-D point and a 3-D vector. How can I determine the first triangle that is passed through by the ray? Now I do not even have an algorithm for this. Any inputs will be appreciated.

Comment: Isn't this more a math than a coding question? Basically, all you need to do is to calculate where the vector is intersecting the 2d planes spanned by the triagles. I would suggest you ask in a math forum. Once you know what to do, the implementation shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Not sure what is your input and output, but the problem sounds like the fundamental idea of ray tracing/ ray casting, so maybe you want to read more about ray tracking/casting, and you may even make use of existing graphics software/hardware to do it for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I would do, is translate the whole data set, subtracting the 3D ray origin. Then rotate the data set so that the ray's 3D vector aligns with the X-axis. See [How to find the orthonormal transformation that will rotate a vector to the x axis?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/114512/how-to-find-the-orthonormal-transformation-that-will-rotate-a-vector-to-the-x-ax).

Now the problem has been converted to filter for triangles that cross the X-axis with a non-negative X-coordinate, and among those find the one whose crossing point has the minimal X-coordinate. So

- For each triangle check where its *plane* crosses the X-axis. See [Determine point of interesction of plane with axis given points of plane](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/948906/determine-point-of-interesction-of-plane-with-axis-given-points-of-plane)
- Then throw away the triangles where that crossing point (on the X-axis) is not within the bounds of the triangle (check for each of the three edges that this point is at the "inner" side of it). See [Check whether a point is within a 3D Triangle](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4322/check-whether-a-point-is-within-a-3d-triangle)
- Throw away the triangles whose crossing point has a negative X-coordinate.
- Among the remaining triangles (that really cross the X-axis on the positive side) find the one with the minimum crossing point in terms of X-coordinate.